# UIScrollView. How do I fix sluggish response for touch-enabled sub-views?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, subview

My scrollView has a drag/zoom -able containerView. The containerView is parent to a UIView subclass of my own design that can respond to tap and drag. My problem: scroll/zoom of the containerView is now total crap, with scroll/zoom sometimes just ignoring swipe attempts entirely. It feels as if touches are now confused as to who is running the show: the scrollView or the containerView sub-classes.

Should I just bail on the sub-classes handling taps and have the scrollView manage all sub-view touches? If so what would that look like? Do I just sub-class UIScrollView and implement the touches quartet of methods?

Thanks in advance.

-Doug

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
theScrollview.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```